meera array n*2 is element in array?
A Meera array is defined to be an array containing only numbers as its elements and for
all n values in the array, the value n*2 is not in the array.
So [3, 5, -2] is a Meera array because 3*2, 5*2 or 2*2 are not in the array.
But [8, 3, 4] is not a Meera array because 4*2=8 and both 4 and 8 are elements found in the array.
My goal is
Write a function that takes an array of numbered elements and prints “I am a Meera array” in the console if its array
does NOT contain n and also n*2 as value. Otherwise, the function prints “I am NOT a
Meera array”

checkMeera([10, 4, 0, 5]) outputs “I am NOT a Meera array” because 5*2 is 10
checkMeera([7, 4, 9]) outputs “I am a Meera array”
checkMeera([1, -6, 4, -3]) outputs “I am NOT a Meera array” because -3*2 is -6

I am confused, help me.

What are you confused about? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Are you receiving any errors? Please have a look at the [tour], [ask] and How do I ask and answer homework questions?

Please look into this code, https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/oNrMjGX

Sounds like you are asking us to do your home work.  You won't learn anything that way.

In Python:
def checkMeera(arr):
   isMeer=False
   for n in arr:
     if n * 2 in arr:
       isMeer=True
     # this break prevent loop from extra checking
       break

   if(isMeer):
    print("I am NOT a Meera array")
   else:
    print("I am a Meera array")

Results:
checkMeera([10, 4, 0, 5])  # Outputs: I am NOT a Meera array
checkMeera([7, 4, 9])      # Outputs: I am a Meera array
checkMeera([1, -6, 4, -3]) # Outputs: I am NOT a Meera array

